# IIS seems to be blocking PayPal code.

Tags: asp.net, iis, paypal

Ive been working on a paypal button and when I run it through Visual Studio it works fine but when I run it through IIS it doesnt redirect to paypal. Im running out of ideas on how to make it work. Help!

My code looks like this:

```
           {string url = "";
            string business = "samplemerchantproj@yahoo.com";  
            string description = "Buy";            
            string country = "US";                  
            string currency = "PHP";                 
            string amount = Label1.Text;

            url += "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" +
                "?cmd=" + "_xclick" +
                "&business=" + business +
                "&amount=" + amount +
                "&lc=" + country +
                "&item_name=" + description +
                "&currency_code=" + currency +
                "&bn=" + "PP%2dBuyNowBF";

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to start an URL on the server? Shouldn't you redirect the browser to that URL?

Comment: I thought since the variables would be generated by the button it should be started, Sorry this is my first time with paypal sandbox. So I should replace start with redirect? Im lost. Been coding for 8hrs straight and im still a student

Comment: This is not sufficient to know what should be done. There is no information where this code is. But it is certain that this will try to start the URL on the server as a separate program that can handle it and that is definitely not what you want.